# Using vba i need to find a certain Trade ID within a folder with over 1000 workbooks and then open it

Tags: vba, excel

I have recently started using VBA code, and after several hours searching the web for ideas or help i have run into a wall. 
Since this site seems to get the best reponses, i was wandering if someone could help me figure out how to Find a certain Trade ID which consists of three letters which are either; VAL, DIV, or LIF; and then a series of numbers.

My Idea was to have the Trade ID typed into a cell, for example C4, and then click a button on the same sheet that would search the entire folder for that trade ID, since they are very unique only 1 file should open maybe two.

Thanks and let me know your thoughts and whether it is possible and how long it would take me to write this code and what sort of code i should use!

### Edit:

Here is my code so far:

```
  Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

   Dim MyObj As Object, MySource As Object, file As Variant
    file = Dir("X:\Ops\Trades\Repository\")
    While (file <> "")
      If InStr(file, Cells(3, 4)) > 0 Then
         MsgBox "found " & file
         Exit Sub
      End If
     file = Dir
    Wend

    End Sub
```

### Edit:

Some Code I found and edited, however just crashes my pc when i run it.

```
 'Definitions
  Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
  Dim MyFiles() As String, Fnum As Long
  Dim mybook As Workbook
  Dim CalcMode As Long
  Dim sh As Worksheet
  Dim ErrorYes As Boolean
  Dim CellSearchBook As Worksheet
  Dim strFile As String


  strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename
  Set CellSearchBook = Workbooks.Open(strFile).Sheets(1)
  CellRef = InputBox("Please enter Horseshoe Cell Reference to search for")
  MyPath = "F:\Ops\Trades\Files\"

  'If no files found
   FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls")
   If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
    End If

   'Array myfiles will be filled
    Fnum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    Fnum = Fnum + 1
    ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To Fnum)
    MyFiles(Fnum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
     End With

     'Run through all files
     If Fnum > 0 Then
     For Fnum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(Fnum))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

       On Error Resume Next
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            For Each ws In mybook.Worksheets

                If .ProtectContents = True Then
                With ws
                Application.ScreenUpdating = False

                    If InStr(1, ws.Range("K11").Value, CellRef, vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
                    ws.Range("H1").Copy Destination:=CellSearchBook.Range("A10")
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    Else
                    End If

                Else
                    ErrorYes = True
                End If
            End With

       If Err.Number > 0 Then
                ErrorYes = True
                Err.Clear
                'Close mybook without saving
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
            Else
                'Save and close mybook
                mybook.Close savechanges:=True
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0
        Else
            'Not possible to open the workbook
            ErrorYes = True
        End If

        Next Fnum
   End If


   End Sub
```

Comment: Try something. When you get stuck, ask for help. (Saying you're stuck before you write any code doesn't count!)

Comment: Is the Trade ID in the filenames or in the actual individual files? Does your current code find any files? Does your current code throw any errors?

Comment: Code Finds the file however the Trade ID is within the file, not in the name.

Comment: Is this on Windows or Mac platform - searching files is done differently...

Comment: Pretty sure VBA is not going to let you check cell values without opening each workbook. And that will be pretty slow for 1000 files.

Comment: I think it would be better to use the OS file indexing option - see for example http://superuser.com/a/60215/196531 for how to search inside files. This will be done "ahead of time" and should be significantly faster. Since I don't work on a PC I can't really give you and example but maybe someone else can act on this suggestion.

Comment: What is the format of your files. Are they very large? You might find that if they are small, converting them to `.csv` makes them readily accessible to any text based search functionality (think `grep`). This would be very much faster than a VBA solution.

Comment: They are all xml files which works better for my needs

Answer (score 0):

If this helps you - it returns an array of filenames:

```
Private Function GetFileList(FileSpec As String) As Variant
'   Returns an array of filenames that match FileSpec
'   If no matching files are found, it returns False

    Dim FileArray() As Variant
    Dim FileCount As Integer
    Dim FileName As String

    On Error GoTo NoFilesFound

    FileCount = 0
    FileName = Dir(FileSpec)
    If FileName = "" Then GoTo NoFilesFound

    'Loop until no more matching files are found
    Do While FileName <> ""
        FileCount = FileCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To FileCount)
        FileArray(FileCount) = FileName
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    GetFileList = FileArray
    Exit Function

    '   Error handler
NoFilesFound:
    GetFileList = False
End Function
```

Comment: Where would this go as its a function? Not a sub routine?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this (This is quickly spliced together from some different modules that I have, so it may not work out of the box):

```
Dim FolderObj, FSO, FileObj As Object
Dim FolderDialog As FileDialog
Dim FolderLocation As String
Dim Check As Boolean

'Create and run dialog box object

Set FolderDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With FolderDialog
    .ButtonName = "Select"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "C:\"
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails

    If .Show = -1 Then
        FolderLocation = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
            Check = True
    Else
         Check = False
    End If

 End With

 'Check if user canceled dialog box
 'Exit if yes

 If Check = False Then

     MsgBox "No Folder Selected"

     Exit Sub

 End If

 'Create a File System Object to be the folder that was selected

 Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

 Set FolderObj = FSO.getfolder(FolderLocation)

 Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
 Dim ExWbk As Workbook



 Set ExApp = New Excel.Application
 ExApp.Visibility = False 'Set the application visibility to false to speed it up and run in the background while it searches your workbooks

 For Each FileObj In FolderObj.Files

      If Right(FileObj.Name, 3) = "xls" Then

           Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open(FolderObj & "\" & FileObj.Name)

           'Some sort of search for the workbook
           'Some sort of return to your workbook

           ExWbk.Close

      end if
 Next
```

Again, this doesn't exactly solve your problem, but it does give you a pretty decent starting point

Comment: Thanks however, the main problem i'm having is how to open each file one after another so that my pc doesn't crash, at the moment they all open at once.

Comment: The above would open each one separately and then close it before opening another. It allows you to identify a folder and then loops through all of the excel files in the folder looking for your values. Notice in the For loop, it opens the workbook, runs whatever find you need, then closes it before going to the next FileObj. It will probably take a lot of time to loop through all 1000 workbooks, but you will only have 1 open at a time.